# ROL AX, 8 is NOP, right?

Tags: assembly, x86

I came across an odd instruction in IDA:

```
ROL AX, 8
```

This is a `NOP`, correct? `AX` is a 1-byte register and it is being rotated by eight. Thus it is just `MOV AX, AX`?

Comment: Even using AL, it still changes rFLAGS so it's not really a 'true' NOP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. `ROL AL,8` would be `NOP`. And `ROL AH,8` would also be `NOP`.
`AX` is a 16-bit register, so `ROL AX, 16` would be `NOP`.

`ROL AX,8` switches the lower BYTE `AL` and the higher BYTE `AH`.
This is an alternative to `XCHG AL, AH`.

The [ROL instruction](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/rcl:rcr:rol:ror) also changes the Overflow and the Carry flag, so it's not really a true `NOP` (See comments).

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: Per the link, *For the ROL and ROR instructions, the original value of the CF flag is not a part of the result, but the CF flag receives a copy of the bit that was shifted from one end to the other.* So wouldn't CF potentially be affected, and make `ROL AX,16`, `ROL AL,8` and `ROL AH,8` not a true `NOP`?

Comment: Yes. According to the given pseudo-code algorithm the CARRY? flag and the OVERFLOW? flag are set after the operation. So it's not a true NOP. And the CARRY? flag sometimes returns the LSB of the result.

Answer (score 7):

This instruction behaves the same as

```
XCHG AH, AL
```

except it also sets `CF` to an undefined value.  This is because `AX` is a 16 bit register.  If this was `ROL AL, 8`, your description would be accurate except that `ROL AL, 8` too sets `CF` to an undefined value.